# How to give custom fields in json2csv library while converting Json to CSV

Tags: node.js, csv, express

I am using `json2csv` library for converting the Json to CSV and I am successful in doing by doing like this

```
status = Utils.getKey(InvoiceStatus, invoice.status);
        if (InvoiceStatus.isOverDue(invoice.status, invoice.dueDate))
          status = 'overdue';
     const fields = [
              'id',
              // 'invoicePrefix + ' - ' + invoiceNo',
              'invoiceDate',
              'dueDate',
              'customerId',
              'customerName',
              {
                label: 'status',
                value: status,

              },
              // 'status',
              'itemDesc',
              'invoiceAmount',
              'dueAmount'
            ];
            const opts = { fields };
            try {
              const parser = new Json2csvParser(opts);
              const csv = parser.parse(invoices);
              res.send(csv);
            } catch (err) {
              console.error(err);
            }
          }
```

But the problem occurs here in this I want to combine two columns of 
`'invoicePrefix + ' - ' + invoiceNo'` and display it but I am not getting way how to do it
and there is one more thing as you can see this line in fields variable

```
{
    label: 'status',
    value: status,

 },
```

As you can see status is some value stored in the variable and I am giving the variable status for the value key but it is not displaying the variable value in CSV so is there any way to solve this so that it also print that variable value.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use  proper syntax:

```
const fields = [
  'id',
  // We set the header label and we provide a function to fill each cell with row data
  {
    label: invoicePrefix + ' - ' + invoiceNo,
    value: (row, field) => row.invoicePrefix + ' - ' + row.invoiceNo
  },
  'invoiceDate',
  'dueDate',
  'customerId',
  'customerName',
  // We set the header label and we provide a function to fill each cell with row data, in this case the same for all rows
  {
    label: 'status',
    value: () => status,
  },
  // 'status',
  'itemDesc',
  'invoiceAmount',
  'dueAmount'
];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use tilde operator to get the actual value of status.
The below enables you to directly use json2csv to download the generated csv, rename the header fields and to flatten the nested object structure.

```
        const fields = [
            '_id', 
            {
                label : 'product_title',
                value: `title`,
            },
            {
                label : 'product_details',
                value: `description`,
            },
            'price', 
            {
                label : 'availability',
                value: `inventory.qty`,
            }
        ];

        const {Parser} = require('json2csv');
        const jsonToCsv = new Parser({fields: fields, unwind: 'inventory', unwindBlank: true});
        try{
            const csv = jsonToCsv.parse(products);
            response.attachment('products.csv')
            response.status(200).send(csv);
        } catch (error) {
            console.log('error:', error.message)
            response.status(500).send(error.message)
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the input json into the required format so that the library will use the proper json and convert without any errors.

Convert to the format like below

```
[
  {
    "Invoice Number": invoicePrefix + ' - ' + invoiceNo,
    "Status": "paid"
  }
]
```

This will result to

```
 Invoice Number, Status
 ABC123, paid
```

As per the doc https://www.npmjs.com/package/json2csv,

```
[{"price":1000},{"price":2000}]
```

will converted into

```
price
1000
2000
```

Please read the docs carefully